# Removing print driver from print server

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, drivers, printer, print-server

How can I remove driver from print server? Actually I remove it with print server snap-in, but I also need to clear all footprints it left (registry, folders etc.). Anyone knows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Deleting a print driver is as simple as using the GUI Printer Management Console](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc783972%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

If you desperately need to remove any trace (though I'm not sure why you'd care, or go through the effort), you'll need to locate the executable/archive file and the location it unpacked to as well.  This kind of thing is what the search function is for.  Likewise, you can search the registry for it based on strings like the filename of the driver, or the make and model of the printer.

The other consideration (and maybe what you're actually asking) is that clients that have connected to this printer will have downloaded the driver, if it's applicable to them.  But again, the steps to deleting it are the same.  On the client(s), it's easiest to just delete the printer.  And if you decide to wipe out all trace, again, locate the executable/archive file and the location it unpacked to, use the search function in the file system, and search through the registry.